# components of a system

Tags: probability

Suppose a system has $10$ components and that at a particular time the $j$th component is working with probability
$1=j$ for $j = 1,2,\ldots,10$. How many components do you expect to be working at that particular time?

Can I get a start on this?

Thanks

Comment: The probability the $j$-th component is working has a typo.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let random variable  $X_j$ be equal to $1$ if the $j$-th component is working, and $0$ otherwise. Then the number of $Y$ of working components is given by 
$$Y=X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_{10}.$$ 
Now use the **linearity of expectation.**  It is easy to compute $E(X_j)$ if you know the probability that the $j$-th component is working.

Note that linearity of expectation holds whether or not the random variables are independent.

Comment: You are welcome. I take it you have no problem about how to finish things. The method of *indicator* random variables is very useful.